# Cannot find type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Services.ImportExportRequest

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell

I am backing up Azure SQL Database with PowerShell. The final part of the script, which is working fine, is this:

```
    Write-Output "Exporting databases"
foreach ($db in $azSqlServerDatabases) {
    $exportRequest = Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport -SqlConnectionContext $azSqlStageConnContext -StorageContainer $container -DatabaseName $db.Name -BlobName ($db.Name + ".bacpac") 
    $exportRequests.Add($exportRequest)
    Write-Output ($db.Name + ".bacpac") 
}
```

I am trying to create generic list:

```
$exportRequests = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Services.ImportExportRequest]'
```

Which must hold the results of the requests. The problem is that when I create the generic list I get an error:

```
    New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Services.ImportExportRequest]]: verify that the assembly containing this type is lo
aded.
At C:...
+ ... tRequests = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.Win ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Where can I find this type? Why it is not included - I am calling Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport successfully and I get the result object - so the type is known already.

Trying to create just one object of the type manually in the Azure PowerShell Console throws the same exception:

```
 PS C:\> $x = new-object 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Services.ImportExportRequest'
new-object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Services.ImportExportRequest]: verify that t
he assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:1 char:6
+ $x = new-object 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Services ...
+      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

PS C:\>
```

I got the output type from [MS documentation.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn546720.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran `getType()` on the object returned by `Start-AzureSQLDatabaseExport`. Looks like you ran into a type issue. The actual type of the object returned by `Start-AzureSQLDatabaseExport` is `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Model.SqlDatabaseServerOperationContext`.

Try declaring your list like below:

```
$exportRequests = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Model.SqlDatabaseServerOperationContext]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @elfisher for the assistance. Here is the final version of my command just in case somebody find it helpful. It helps me export all the dbs from azure server during dev and test.

```
# The command will prompt only once for most parameters during one session
param(
[string] $azSubscriptionId, 
[string] $azStorageName, 
[string] $azStorageKey, 
[string] $azContainerName,
[string] $azSqlServerName, 
[string] $azSqlServerUserName, 
[string] $azSqlServerPassword)

#if you want to clean up all globally created vars => Remove-Variable -Name 'az*'
 Remove-Variable -Name 'az*'

#Remove-Variable -Name 'azAccount' # clean up acc credentials. Can be removed but once in a while the credentials for the account get expired

#region azAccount
$azAccount = Get-AzureAccount
if(!$azAccount)
{
    Do
    {
       Write-Output "No azure account. Prompting ..."
       $azAccount = Add-AzureAccount
    } While (!$azAccount)
    Set-Variable -Name azAccount -Value $azAccount -Scope Global
    $azAccount = Get-AzureAccount
}
#endregion

#region azSubscriptionId
if(!$azSubscriptionId) 
{
    Do
    {
        Write-Output "No subscription Id. Prompting ..."
        $azSubscriptionId = Read-Host "Subscription Id"
    } While (!$azSubscriptionId)
    Write-Output "Input for subscription Id $azSubscriptionId"
    Set-Variable -Name azSubscriptionId -Value $azSubscriptionId -Scope Global
}
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionId  $azSubscriptionId
Write-Output "Selected subscription Id $azSubscriptionId"
#endregion

#region azStorageName
if(!$azStorageName) 
{
    Do
    {
        Write-Output "No storage name. Prompting ..."
        $azStorageName = Read-Host "storage name"
    } While (!$azStorageName)
    Set-Variable -Name storageName -Value $azStorageName -Scope Global
}
#endregion

#region azStorageKey
if(!$azStorageKey) 
{
    Do
    {
        Write-Output "No storage key. Prompting ..."
        $azStorageKey = Read-Host "storage key"
    } While (!$azStorageKey)
    Set-Variable -Name azStorageKey -Value $azStorageKey -Scope Global
}
#endregion

#region azContainerName
if(!$azContainerName) 
{
    Do
    {
        Write-Output "No container name. Prompting ..."
        $azContainerName = Read-Host "container name"
    } While (!$azContainerName)
    Set-Variable -Name azContainerName -Value $azContainerName -Scope Global
}
#endregion

#region azSqlServerName
if(!$azSqlServerName) 
{
    Do
    {
        Write-Output "No sql server name. Prompting ..."
        $azSqlServerName = Read-Host "sql server name"
    } While (!$azSqlServerName)
    Set-Variable -Name azSqlServerName -Value $azSqlServerName -Scope Global
}
#endregion

#region azSqlServer
if(!$azSqlServer) 
{   
    Write-Output "No sql server variable stored on this PC. Prompting ..."
    $azSqlServer = Get-AzureSqlDatabaseServer -ServerName $azSqlServerName 
    Set-Variable -Name azSqlServer -Value $azSqlServer -Scope Global
}
#endregion

#region azSqlServerCredenials
if(!$azSqlServerCredenials) 
{
    Do
    {
        Write-Output "No sql server credentials. Prompting ..."
        $azSqlServerCredenials = Get-Credential "Enter Credentials for $azSqlServerName"
    } While (!$azSqlServerCredenials)
    Set-Variable -Name azSqlServerCredenials -Value $azSqlServerCredenials -Scope Global
}
#endregion

#region Sql connection context
if(!$azSqlCtx)
{
    Write-Output "No Sql Server Context. Creating..."
    $azSqlCtx = New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerContext -ServerName $azSqlServer.ServerName -Credential $azSqlServerCredenials
    Set-Variable -Name azSqlCtx -Value $azSqlCtx -Scope Global
     Write-Output "Sql Server Context for $azSqlServer.ServerName created."
}

#endregion

#region Storage connection context
if(!$azStorageCtx)
{
    Write-Output "No Storage Context. Creating..."
    $azStorageCtx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $azStorageName -StorageAccountKey $azStorageKey
    Set-Variable -Name azStorageCtx -Value $azStorageCtx -Scope Global
    Write-Output "Storage context for $azStorageName created."
}
#endregion

#region Storage container ref
if(!$azStorageContainer)
{
    Write-Output "No container ref. Creating for $azContainerName"
    $azStorageContainer = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $azContainerName -Context $azStorageCtx
    Set-Variable -Name azStorageContainer -Value $azStorageContainer -Scope Global
    Write-Output "Container ref to $azStorageContainer created."
}
#endregion

#region Sql Databases ref
if(!$azSqlServerDatabases)
{
    Write-Output "No Sql Databases array ref. Creating..."
    $azSqlServerDatabases = Get-AzureSqlDatabase -ConnectionContext $azSqlCtx
    Set-Variable -Name azSqlServerDatabases -Value $azSqlServerDatabases -Scope Global
    Write-Output "Sql Databases array ref created."
}
#endregion

#region actual export of azure databases
$exportRequests = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.List[Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.SqlDatabase.Model.SqlDatabaseServerOperationContext]'

Write-Output "Exporting databases"
foreach ($db in $azSqlServerDatabases) {
    $exportRequest = Start-AzureSqlDatabaseExport -SqlConnectionContext $azSqlCtx -StorageContainer $azStorageContainer -DatabaseName $db.Name -BlobName ($db.Name + ".bacpac") 
    $exportRequests.Add($exportRequest)
    Write-Output ($db.Name + ".bacpac") 
}
#endregion

#import dbs back into your local server

#cd [FOLDERPATH]
#$goodlist = dir
# probably the correct path
##C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120
#cd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DAC\bin'
#foreach($i in $goodlist){ $name = $i.Name; $namer = $i.Name.Substring(0, $i.Name.length - 7); .\SqlPackage.exe /a:Import /sf:[FOLDERPATH]\$name /tdn:$namer /tsn:[SERVERNAME] }
```